# Does accessing NODE_ENV make sense in front end code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment

I have a react/node app that I'm deploying. One of the components attempts to access NODE_ENV in order to determine which host URL to use (localhost or heroku).

I now realize that even though NODE_ENV is being set to production, it's always 'undefined' in the browser context, because the environment is not node.

Since I can't access NODE_ENV from my react component, how do I dynamically set the host server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good practice to use `NODE_ENV` variables for things like API URL.

If you used [create-react-app](/questions/tagged/create-react-app), all environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_` should already be accessible with `process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLE_NAME`.
You can try `REACT_APP_TEST=5 npm start` then `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_TEST)`.

If you are not using `create-react-app`, you have to import them in your webpack config.

You can also choose to define the `process.env` variables for the app through a `.env` file using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer was the most precise. I was going to try your solution, but first ran webpack -p instead of just webpack. That sets the environment automatically I guess, so I didn't need to touch the webpack.config.

Answer (score 7):

> One of the components attempts to access NODE_ENV in order to determine which host URL to use (localhost or heroku).

Yup, absolutely!

There's a difference here between having stuff around at build time, and at runtime. You'll have `NODE_ENV` around at buildtime - say you run `webpack` or something to build some JSX, or whatever.

You won't have `NODE_ENV` around at runtime, when the user visits your site. There's no concept of environmental variables in that web browsing context.

What I've done in this case is to programmatically create a file that will conditionally have the web server URL. Or even captures the `NODE_ENV` and puts the value in the application for later.

As a practical example: in a React project I was on a couple years ago we autogenerated our index.html file. This was a silly little file, bringing in our `<script>` Javascript tags we require and adding a `<div>` for the React app to render in. In the template language we did something like this:

index.html.templ

```
<html><body ENVIRONMENT="$NODE_ENV"></body></html>
```

after that file came out the other end of our build pipeline, it would look like this for our production build:

index.html

```
<html><body ENVIRONMENT="PRODUCTION"></body></html>
```

Then we just used normal DOM Javascript to grab the body element and check the attribute (then put it in a Redux store? I forget exactly).

At user visit time, we have an apparently hard-coded value of "production". But you and I know better!

**Update**: I forgot, there's actually two ways of doing this *in Webpack itself*, without using an external template tool and generating a file like I describe here!

1. Use the WebPack define plugin. This will essentially add another step to your transpiling phase: one that goes in and replaces a literal string with some other literal string. So `let e = "NODE_ENV"` would become `let e = "production"`. There's a [good Medium blog post about defineplugin](https://medium.com/@justintulk/passing-environment-variables-into-your-code-with-webpack-cab09d8974b0), and it's kind of cool.
2. There's some environmental variable support in Webpack itself. Apparently if you run webpack with `webpack --env.NODE_ENV=production`. Then... maybe you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` ? The [Webpack documentation for this feature](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) isn't exactly clear on this

Comment: Good explanation. I don't use React, but I do sometimes have a middleware layer (or whatever) server-side that injects the environment variables that I need into the template layer. Then my template can set this object within a namespace in the DOM, e.g. `window.myAppNamespace.env = {...}`.

Comment: Webpack seems to set client side env variables based on NODE_ENV. That's my assumption at least, since when I ran webpack -p, everything worked, even though my react components were still accessing only process.env.NODE_ENV.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot: there's a thing about that! I've updated my answer here!

Answer (score 3):

You could check NODE_ENV in index.html by using:

```
if ("%NODE_ENV%" === "production") {
  // ...do production stuff
} else {
  // ...do development stuff
}
```

When index.html is compiled in a production environment it will look something like this

```
if ("production" === "production") {
  // ...do production stuff
} else {
  // ...do development stuff
}
```

Comment: What is the mechanism that translates `"%NODE_ENV%"` in the source code into `"production"` in the compiled code? Does webpack automatically perform replacement of anything matching `%<code>%`? If so, how is the "code" `NODE_ENV` resolved to refer to `process.env.NODE_ENV`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the scope here. Node is a javascript runtime which runs as a server to handle backend stuff. NODE_ENV is a variable used in node to set up environment variables, thus, it is only accessible in the node environment, not in the client side.

Anyway in the first place, there is no reason why you would want to expose your config variables to your client side (that is a vulnerability issue). If it is related to some configs that relies on your server side variables, you have to set it in your client side independently. A use case I can imagine is defining a socket host and port to listen from the client side to the server side. Hope that clears things up :)

Imagine the life cycle:

1. client requests
2. node server processes and responds to request
3. response is served through the browser

Comment: Great answer: makes very clear that NODE_ENV is not exposed in the client " thus, it is only accessible in the node environment, not in the client side". So many comments on this topic do not clearly state this as you have here. Thanks!