# When I use my Heroku Config Variables in my react app, they come back as undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, config

I've built a simple resume [website](https://luisdriver.herokuapp.com/) using react; hosted on heroku, its code can be found [here](https://github.com/LEscobar-Driver/MyWebsite). I am using a service [emailjs](https://www.emailjs.com/) to allow others to reach me via email. Locally I am using `config/secrets.json` to load variables I need to initiate the emailjs object. I added all variables contained in `config/secrets.json` to my heroku app located at `Settings` `Config Vars`.

You can see how I attempt to access those environment variables [here](https://github.com/LEscobar-Driver/MyWebsite/blob/master/components/Footer.js#L90).

When I take a look at the console, I see that `process.env.INIT_USER` outputs `undefined`? I have `INIT_USER` in my heroku app and see it on the cli with command `heroku config -a app_name`.

I cannot access my environment variables despite the fact that I see them on my herokus app settings.

My application is deployed in Heroku and I use Heroku Pipelines for my deployment and build process.

Comment: I think for reactjs to have the variables embedded into the build it still has to follow the naming convention of `REACT_APP_WHATEVERNAME`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does accessing NODE\_ENV make sense in front end code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244473/does-accessing-node-env-make-sense-in-front-end-code)

Comment: @ShawnYap yes I tried that as well. I still get `undefined` for `process.env.REACT_APP_INIT_USER`.

Comment: @ceejayoz are you saying that my website cant actually see `process.env` vars? I added the needed config vars to heroku, but that is just to build the app? I need to pass in my auth token tothe `emailjs` object each time a user attempts to email me.

Comment: Did you create your project with create-react-app? Doesn't seem like you have react-script in your package to support react environment variables. You might need to use `dotenv` package for your variables. env var resource link https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: @ShawnYap No. I am using [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/), built from scratch

Comment: @LuisEscobar-Driver Your *front-end* can't see `process.env` by default, because the environment may contain *extremely* sensitive data like your database credentials or API keys.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes that is my problem. I am attempting to see config vars in client side. I need that sensative info in client side. Any ideas on the best way to do that knowing I am using next js & react

Comment: @LuisEscobar-Driver Looks like https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5 says you can do it via the Webpack config.

Comment: @LuisEscobar-Driver Important thing to note here is that React embeds the values of env vars during build time, not during run time. So when setting the value of a config var in Heroku (make sure to prepend with REACT_APP_) you'll need to rebuild and redeploy your app to have the new var be available to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the ENV vars in heroku *after* deploying the app, try redeploying the app.

With a create-react-app app (which uses buildpack), I found that the `process.env` variables were set during the build phase of the deployment. So, updating the variables in the heroku dashboard after the build was completed did not update the variables in the `process.env` object. Redeploying the app updated the `process.env` object with the env variables I had set.

This also causes problems with pipelines because Heroku does not rebuild the app slug when you promote it to production. This means the promoted app will use the `process.env` variables from your staging app, so you have to make sure your staging app has the same variables that you want to use in production.

Big design flaw on Heroku's part IMO.

Comment: yeah, so first place the env variables in heroku -> config first and then push the code. otherwise if you have already pushed the code then just re-push it with any small change just to make variables work

Answer (score 0):

I had to actually uninstall my globally installed create-react-app:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and opt for this app generation command instead:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```